# Extension for Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a simple server in Sinatra, like

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class Server < Sinatra::Base

  get '/' do
    "root"
  end

  get '/api/:apiname' do
    "return api from module #{params.apiname}"
  end

end
```

I want to be able to include modules for each api, which could use Sinatra DSL. It could be like:

```
module SomeApi
  get '/api_method'
    "result of api call"
  end
end
```

Then I want to include `SomeApi` module to my `Server` class, to be able to get api call result from url "http://localhost/someapi/api_method". Is it possible to change my code to be able to do this, or should I use another framework then Sinatra? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you will find the `map` method from Rack useful. With it, you could do something like:

config.ru:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require './app'

map('/api1'){ run API1 }
map('/api2'){ run API2 }
map('/'){ run Server }
```

app.rb:

```
class Server < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    "root"
  end

  get '/foo' do
    "foo from Server"
  end
end

class API1 < Sinatra::Base
  get '/foo' do
    "foo from API1"
  end
end

class API2 < Sinatra::Base
  get '/foo' do
    "foo from API2"
  end
end
```

start server:

```
$ thin start
>> Using rack adapter
>> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

test it:

```
$ curl localhost:3000
root%
$ curl localhost:3000/foo     
foo from Server%    
$ curl localhost:3000/api1/foo
foo from API1%
$ curl localhost:3000/api2/foo
foo from API2%
```